# split variables from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have an array of urls that get pulled in with "videoJsonUrl" and i'm trying to get a variable from the urls that come in _id=XXXXXXXX
this is what I have so far, which works if I add the url in it manually:

```
const VideoUrl = "https://player.vimeo.com/external/444937644.sd.mp4?s=a6aa1fdd06df967a0cfc300dbfef1a24927e4f61&profile_id=165&oauth2_token_id=57447761"
const strs = VideoUrl.split('_id=');
const videoId = strs.at(-1)
console.log("Get Content Video ID",videoId);
```

I cant for the life of me get it to work "videoJsonUrl" though, I think the problem is that "videoJsonUrl" actually contains 3 urls, like this:

[image]

can anyone give me any pointers on how to do it?

Comment: Are the 3 urls different? Can you add examples of them in text to your question?

Comment: So, do you want to get the `id` from all the `URLs`? I see that all URLs have the same `id`

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a new URL object from each address, then use its [`searchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) property to get the parameter value of interest:

```js
const urls = [
  'https://player.vimeo.com/external/444937644.sd.mp4?s=a6aa1fdd06df967a0cfc300dbfef1a24927e4f61&profile_id=165&oauth2_token_id=57447761',
  'https://player.vimeo.com/external/444937644.sd.mp4?s=a6aa1fdd06df967a0cfc300dbfef1a24927e4f61&profile_id=165&oauth2_token_id=57447823',
  'https://player.vimeo.com/external/444937644.sd.mp4?s=a6aa1fdd06df967a0cfc300dbfef1a24927e4f61&profile_id=165&oauth2_token_id=57447915',
];

const results = urls.map(url => {
  const id = new URL(url).searchParams.get('oauth2_token_id');
  return id;
});

console.log(results); // [ "57447761", "57447823", "57447915" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

URLSearchParams instances have a built-in entries iterator so this should also be fine:

```
    const urls = [
    'https://player.vimeo.com/external/444937644.sd.mp4?s=a6aa1fdd06df967a0cfc300dbfef1a24927e4f61&profile_id=165&oauth2_token_id=57447761',
    'https://player.vimeo.com/external/444937644.sd.mp4?s=a6aa1fdd06df967a0cfc300dbfef1a24927e4f61&profile_id=165&oauth2_token_id=57447823',
    'https://player.vimeo.com/external/444937644.sd.mp4?s=a6aa1fdd06df967a0cfc300dbfef1a24927e4f61&profile_id=165&oauth2_token_id=57447915',
  ];
  
const results = urls.map(url => {
    const { oauth2_token_id } = Object.fromEntries(new URL(url).searchParams)
    return oauth2_token_id;
});
  
  console.log(results) // [ '57447761', '57447823', '57447915' ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Since ids are all numeric, use a regular expression with a capturing group.

```js
const rx = /_id=(\d+)/g
const m = rx.exec(url)
const ids=[]
while (m) {
 ids.push(m[1])
 m = rx.exec(url)
}
```

Use a `Set` if you need unique values.  Use a `Map` and another capturing group if you need to capture the prefixed id name.

Or just parse the query string and get the values directly from the query map.